# Timed Shuddown Fails

Tags: shutdown

Having recently upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04, I've run across an unusual problem. When I go to shutdown via the menu selecting shutdown and letting it time out for 60 seconds, the system seems to go through most of the steps, gets to what looks like one of the opening screens (before you get the logon screen) and then hangs using what appears to be a lot of CPU time (the laptop fan kicks in). In this state, not even REISUB does anything! Pressing the immediate button works normally. Weird. Any thoughts?
k

Comment: Might be interesting to see the results of the log. Something like journalctl --since "X minutes ago" after a forced reboot might turn up something interesting.

Comment: I'd love to supply a log... I  don't know how to do that...

Comment: You can see the log by opening the terminal and typing sudo journalctl --since "X minutes ago" (where X is a minute just before the shutdown). It will prompt for your password.

Comment: Mordoc: Well, I attempted to do the timed shutdown and, surprise! It worked. Maybe it was fixed in one of the updates... ? Thanks for the journal tip. Seems like it'd come in handy! k

Comment: Glad you have a working system as you wanted it! Have a great day...